# Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax request to check the database if this username is available, but when trying to run the script in the console it give me an error that the is an Uncaught SyntaxError- Unexpected Identifier. I have checked my code but can not find the problem. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Here is my code.

**main.js**

```
$('#checkusername').keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
        var username = $('#checkusername').val();

        url: 'usernamecheck-validate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {checkusername: username},
        success: function(data){
            $('.status').html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

**register.php**

```
 <form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="checkusername" class="form" placeholder="Enter Username"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form" placeholder="Enter Password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="register-validation-button" class="form-btn" value="Register Account">
 </form>
```

Comment: You can't have a `var username = ...` statement *inside* an object (`{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `username` *outside* of the object you provide to the `$.ajax` call:

```
$('#checkusername').keyup(function() {
    var username = $('#checkusername').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'usernamecheck-validate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            checkusername: username
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.status').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much i changed it and it started working like a charm. Once again i appreciate the help you provided.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use *var in ajax like you did in OP* .. use it like this

```
$('#checkusername').keyup(function() {
   var username = $('#checkusername').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'usernamecheck-validate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {checkusername: username},
        success: function(data){
            $('.status').html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now. Once again thank you for the help.